# Function added to C code and swig interface not recognized; "no attribute 'set_latency'"

Tags: python, c, swig, ftdi

I am using [libmpsse](https://github.com/devttys0/libmpsse/tree/master/src) to communicate with an FTDI chip, and in order to increase throughput I wanted to add a function to the C code to lower the latency of the chip (supported by [libFTDI](https://www.intra2net.com/en/developer/libftdi/documentation/group__libftdi.html#ga3e0227b0c7aa859d2d2afb5ffa4c8466)), and then interface the function using swig to use with Python. However, when I call the function created, I get an error saying there is no attribute 'set_latency' (details below).

To mpsse.c, I added at the bottom:

```
int set_latency(struct mpsse_context* mpsse, int latency) {
    return ftdi_set_latency_timer(&mpsse->ftdi, latency);
}
```

To mpsse.h, I added after the Version function:

```
int set_latency(struct mpsse_context* mpsse, int latency);
```

I then recompiled the swig interface using:

```
make clean
swig -python mpsse.i
gcc -fpic -c mpsse.c mpsse_wrap.c -I/usr/include/python2.7/
gcc -shared mpsse.o mpsse_wrap.o -o _mpsse.so
```

I am not familiar with swig, but in mpsse.i, mpsse.h is included which I believe means that it doesn't need to be changed.

After using swig, this is added to the code generated by swig in pylibmpsse.py:

```
def set_latency(mpsse, latency):
    return _pylibmpsse.set_latency(mpsse, latency)
set_latency = _pylibmpsse.set_latency
```

And I call the generated code by adding this to mpsse.py:

```
def set_latency(self, latency):
    return _mpsse.set_latency(self.context, latency)
```

This is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bw-test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from mpsse import *
  File "[...]/libmpsse-master/src/mpsse.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pylibmpsse as _mpsse
  File "[...]/libmpsse-master/src/pylibmpsse.py", line 455, in <module>
    set_latency = _pylibmpsse.set_latency
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'set_latency'
```

The error seems to imply there is something wrong with the pylibmpsse.py file or _pylibmpsse (generated with swig_import_helper() ), but I am not familiar enough with swig to know. I have tried explicitly declaring the function I added in mpsse.i and some formatting changes I saw in similar stackoverflow questions, but none changed the error message. If anyone can provide some insight on what I am doing wrong it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the SWIG-generated extension module is `_pylibmpsse`, so your final gcc command should be:

```
gcc -shared mpsse.o mpsse_wrap.o -o _pylibmpsse.so
```

In other words, I suspect you never did replace the original SWIG module.

Comment: Isn't this more of a comment than an answer?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I explained to the OP exactly what the problem was and a solution. Can you elaborate on why it seems like a comment?

Comment: Thanks for the response!

I tried compiling as you suggested and it gave errors for functions that were already part of the library, even when compiling without my change, so I don't think this is the problem. 

By the swig-generated extemsion module do you mean the pylibmpsse.py created by swig? I import pylibmpsse as _mpsse when using the functions in my code. 


In the SWIG-generated code there is a chunk of code that imports something as _pylibmpsse, so maybe there is something from with the c code or the c compilation?

Comment: Could you try reversing the order of input object files: gcc -shared mpsse_wrap.o mpsse.o -o _pylibmpsse.so

Comment: I flipped the object files, but get the same error compiling as before (posted above) unfortunately.

Comment: Ah, freq2div is in a different object. Please refer to the project Makefile:
https://github.com/devttys0/libmpsse/blob/master/src/Makefile.in#L42

Your command should be:
    `gcc -shared mpsse_wrap.o mpsse.o support.o -o _pylibmpsse.so -lftdi` or maybe `-lftdi1`, I can't tell just from the code what is the correct one for your system (https://github.com/devttys0/libmpsse/blob/master/src/configure.ac#L20).

Comment: I tried the new command and it still says freq2div is undefined. I also added -L/usr/local/lib to declare library path, no change. I didn't realize the makefile had a function to compile the swig stuff - I tried that one too using "make pyswig-build" but got the original error message about set_latency.

Comment: Could you post the output of `make clean pyswig-build`? Here is mine: https://pastebin.com/pGzQFiTj

Comment: A few other dumps: https://pastebin.com/Jw3gTn0Z Please compare these with yours.

Comment: I get 4 'unused variable' warnings when running 'make clean pyswig-build'. Other than that they are pretty much identical. Pastebin: https://pastebin.com/64wuzGTG

Comment: Can you please post your complete code to a github branch?